# Regex that checks every instance of cast() is preceded by safe_

Tags: regex

I'm very new to making Regexes and wondering how to check a string (SQL Query) where every instance of "cast()" is directly preceded by "safe_" (i.e. if "cast()" is used, it's always used as "safe_cast()")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This expression

```
(?<=\bsafe_)cast\(\)
```

might likely check for those with `safe_`, and

```
(?<!\bsafe_)cast\(\)
```

for those without.

The expression is explained on the top right panel of [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/o82IVR/1/) if you wish to explore/simplify/modify it.

#### [DEMO 2](https://regex101.com/r/zPE5dW/1/)

---

Edit:

If you wish to exclude `safe_cast()`, this expression might be an option:

```
^(?!(.*\bsafe_cast\(\))).*$
```

#### [DEMO 3](https://regex101.com/r/mTk7sX/1/)

Comment: You probably want to use a negative lookbehind assertion to find those instances that are *not* preceded by `safe_`.

Comment: Sorry should've been more clear. This is to test a SQL Query such that any string that doesn't contain substring "cast()" will match and if a string contains substring "cast()", all instances of "cast()" are preceded by "safe_" which will make the entire string match.

Comment: @Emma +1 Regex matching is powerful.